# Rails: callbacks from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, mixins

I try to do this:

app/models/my_model.rb:

```
class MyModel <  ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
  ...
end
```

lib/my_module.rb:

```
module MyModule
  before_destroy :my_func    #!

  def my_func
    ...
  end
end
```

but I get an error:

```
undefined method `before_destroy' for MyModule:Module
```

How can I correct it.

Also I'm new to ruby. What type has these "attributes": before_destroy, validates, has_many?
Are they variables or methods or what?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`before_destroy`, `validates`, etc. are not attributes or anything like that. These are method calls.

In ruby, the body of a class is all executable code, meaning that each line of the class body is executed by the interpeter just like a method body would.

`before_destroy :my_func` is a usual ruby method call. The method that gets called is `before_destroy`, and it receives a symbol `:my_func` as an argument. This method is looked up in the class (or module) in the scope of which it is called.

So moving on to your question, I think now you should understand that when the interpreter loads your module

```
module MyModule
  before_destroy :my_func    #!

  def my_func
    ...
  end
end
```

it starts executing its body and searches for the method `before_destroy` in this module and cannot find one. What you want to do is call this method not on the module, but rather on the class where the module is included. For that we have a common idiom using the `Module#included` method:

```
module MyModule
  module InstanceMethods
    def my_func
      ...
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    base.before_destroy :my_func
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In lib/my_module.rb, do this:

```
  class MyInheritedClass <  ActiveRecord::Base
    before_destroy :my_func
    def my_func
       ...
    end
  end
```

In app/models/my_model.rb, do this:

```
class MyModel < MyInheritedClass
  ...
end
```

There is no before_destroy filter in the module you are trying to create above. What my code does is creating a class that will inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and that will be your template class which all your other classes can inherit from. The template class also contains all properties of ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 0):

u can correct this by removing before_destroy from MyModule and place it in MyModel instead

before_destroy and other callbacks are only available to classes which extends ActiveRecord::Base, more info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

hope this helps =)